# Processing java decrease until certain number

Tags: javascript, java, processing

I've got a variable called `tn`. I want to increase it until `50` and if it reaches 50 I want to decrease it back to 0 and if it reaches 0 I want to increase it again and `loop through it`

```
float tn = 0;
  tn += 0.1;

 if(tn >= 50){
   tn -= 0.1;
 }
```

I've got this but now im stuck at *how* to decrease by 0.1 until it reaches 0 and if it reaches 0 *how* to increase it back to 50 and so on.

Comment: You probably need a variable to track which direction you're going

Comment: Sounds like a perfect recipe for an infinite loop.

Comment: Any suggestion @khelwood?

Answer (score 2):

Track whether you are going up or down in a variable. Alter the variable when you hit an endpoint.

For instance:

```
float delta = 0.1f;
float tn = 0f;

// inside your loop:
    tn += delta;
    if (delta > 0 && tn >= 50 || delta < 0 && tn <= 0) {
        delta = -delta
    }
```

Comment: Have to figure out out exactly because it is going _way_ to fast , i think. I dont know exactly but atleast it is going up and down the correct way

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers telling you to use a `boolean`, you could just create a variable that keeps track of how much to add, then multiply it by `-1` to switch directions:

```
float value = 0;
float add = .1;

void draw(){

   value += add;
   println(value);

   if(value >= 50 || value <= 0){
      add *= -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  boolean goUp = true; 
  float tn = 0;    
  while (true) { 
   if(goUp) {
      tn += 0.1;
      if(tn == 50){
        goUp = false;
      }
   } else {
      tn -= 0.1;
      if(tn == 0){
        goUp = true;
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'm a firm believer that an answer should not just work but should also educate the OP as to why what they were trying was wrong and what was done to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

can do it like this

```
void myfun(){
float tn = 0;
boolean maxReached = false;

while(true){
    if(!maxReached){
       tn += 0.1;     
    }else{
       tn -= 0.1;
    }
    if(tn>=50){
       maxReached=true;  
    }
    if(tn <= 0) {
      maxReached = false; 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
    float tn = 0.0f;
    for (;;) {
        for (; tn < 50; tn += 0.1f) 
            System.out.println("tn + " + tn);
        for (; tn >0; tn -= 0.1f) 
            System.out.println("tn - " + tn);
    }
```